# Exchange 2013 powershell mailbox recovery

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013, data-recovery, mailbox

I wish to script the procedure to bring the mailbox back from Dumpster.
In my normal procedure I do as below

```
'$Dumpster = Get-MailboxServer | Get-Mailboxstatistics'
'$Dumpster | ? {$_.DisplayName -like "Display Name"} | ft DisplayName, MailboxGUID, ItemCount, TotalItemSize, Database -AutoSize




DisplayName     MailboxGuid                          ItemCount TotalItemSize                  Database
-----------     -----------                          --------- -------------                  --------
Display Name 437cdd37-d54c-4f96-aae0-8d523707ca41         1 3.891 KB (3,984 bytes)         DB53 '
```

and then create an emailbox just like the deleted one and recover it from dupmster as below

```
'New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceDatabase "DB53" -SourceStoreMailbox "437cdd37-d54c-4f96-aae0-8d523707ca41" -TargetMailbox dname@domain.tld -AllowLegacyDNMismatch'
```

So the MailboxGUID and Source-mailboxDB I wish to get them into two variables.
How can I do it?

Comment: @yagmoth555 thx for editing I am really not good in using this editor here :)

Comment: You've already got the info in the Dumpster object, just call the subvalues.```$Dumpster.MailboxGuid``` Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

$Dumpster = Get-MailboxServer | Get-Mailboxstatistics | ? {$_.DisplayName -like "name"}

Then replace the specific value with $Dumpster.DisplayName   $Dumpster.MailboxGUID

Comment: I solved it like below
'    $Anzeigename = Read-Host -Prompt "Geben den genauen Anzeigenamen ein"
$Dumpster = Get-MailboxServer | Get-Mailboxstatistics
$tere = ($Dumpster|? {$_.DisplayName -like $Anzeigename|Sort ItemCount}).MailboxGuid
$MBguid = ($tere -split "`n")[1]
$NDBname = ($Dumpster|? {$_.DisplayName -like $Anzeigename|Sort ItemCount}).DatabaseName
$DBname = ($ndbname -split "`n")[1]
$TargetMBox = Read-Host -Prompt "geben Ziel-Mail-Adresse ein" 
New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceDatabase "$DBname" -SourceStoreMailbox "$MBguid" -TargetMailbox $TargetMBox -AllowLegacyDNMismatch'